# Instagram API request limit

Tags: api, instagram

My question is really simple, what is the actual request limit for Instagram API for liking a single media.I have checked the Instagram API documentation and from there I got the maximum limit of request is 5000 per hours for a single access_token.

Is there any limit for request to like a media number of times from a single access_token? May be this question asked many times, but I still don't get any satisfactory answer. Thanks in advance. Your help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Rate limits for liking media are much lower than the global rate limits of 5,000 per hour.

- Likes per hour for unsigned calls: 30 per token
- Likes per hour for signed calls: 100 per token

See Endpoint-Specific Rate Limits on this page: https://instagram.com/developer/limits/

Answer (score 0):

The request limit seems to vary for certain features (such as liking).

See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20170917

Comment: No problem. Came across your question and that answer looking for the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

creates several client_id and so each will have one rate limit of 5000

they can be created here:

https://instagram.com/developer/clients/manage/